# Delegate and impersonate as a user with admin/app credentials

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

One thing I do currently in an enterprise app is logon to a single admin email account that has delegation over other users and using delegation, we are able to manipulate email/calendar/contacts of users.

I'm looking to use the Microsoft Graph API and I have managed to use admin delegation and gain access to various resources, however last modified (on Onedrive/Sharepoint) is showing the app instead of an individual user.

I understand I can use Oauth and logon as individual users, capture a token and then do what I need under the context of that user, but, I need to do this server side where tasks run. Is there anyway to use admin approved delegation/impersonation from the app so that the users don't have to signin?

```
e.g. standard that works:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/my-site.office.com/drive/root:/file.txt:/content

Looking to add a user tag, but this doesn't work:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/user/{id-of-user}/sites/my-site.office.com/drive/root:/file.txt:/content`
```

After searching for ages, the closest I have read seems to be [in here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of) however, I was wondering if there was a standard way of doing this - I haven't been able to get the JWT part of this working (and not sure if this is even the correct thing I am looking for).

Comment: You can handle JWT request by setting the grant_type value to urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of

Comment: @MarileeTurscak-MSFT - Thanks, this looks like what I want to achieve, however, I have been using Postman and no matter what I try, I just can't seem to actually get this to work... (using PSK)... The only code examples I can find are c# and I'm really struggling to adapt. I don't suppose you are able to point me in the right direction/is this something that is possible from Postman?

Comment: Have you looked into these guides? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/23/using-postman-to-call-the-microsoft-graph-api-using-authorization-code-flow/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code